# Wordpress blog website apache and IIS subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, wordpress, directory

The issue is this :

Our company has a website hosted on an IIS server. I have recently been given the task to configure a WordPress server for an eventual WordPress blog so that our social media employee could test and see how it works.

This was completed successfully and easily on a new server and on a WAMP configuration. The website was published as wordpress.domain.com and works fine.

HOWEVER! I have now been requested to ensure that the soon-to-go-online blog would be accessible through the address domain.com/blog.

Is there a way to modify the original company website and simple redirect the /blog to the Apache WordPress website? If not, is there a way to transfer the wordpress.domain.com on the IIS server hosting the main website and keep the configuration? Is there a better solution that I haven't thought about (probably)? If so, what would you all suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Application Request Routing (ARR) IIS module from Microsoft.  The situation you are in basically requires a reverse proxy which the ARR should be able to provide.  More information can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting).